# IBM Edge Components Load balancer for IPV4's executor is not getting started?

Tags: websphere

I have installed LB for IPV4 on centos 6.9, dsserver starts successfully but when I start executor it gives me below error.

Error : kernel was not loaded (Error_Loading)

I know that it is deprecated and support will end in September, but for now I have to make this working. Any suggestions will be helpfull.

Below is the snap of the server.log file.

[image: Edge_Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using unsupported OS. Second LB for IPV4 has strong dependency on the kernel level.

You didn't specify the version you are using. From the log it looks like you are using 8.0.0.0. You should never use initial version. Please update to the latest fixpack.

I'd strongly suggest to use LB for IPv4 and IPv6 version, if possible, it is much less kernel dependent.

Comment: On Linux platforms, LB for IPv4 is kernel dependent and you must ensure LB has support for the kernel or the executor will not start. Support for kernel 2.6.32-696 was added into 8.5.5.14 which is after WAS v8.0 was out of support so version 8 will not work on this kernel.